# Authentication script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working on a script that does an authentication job one time for products with factory code to avoid the fake products.
My end goal is:
- Test a user input value if it matches a list of original codes.
- if the input is checked for the first time and matches one of the original codes-list redirects to a specific web page.
- if the user input is checked for the second time and matches before one of the original codes-checked-list display a paragraph.
- if the input is checked and NOT matches show FAKE.

Here what I write so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var originalCodes = ['123','1234','12345'];
  var userInputCode = document.getElementById('userInputCode');
  $('form').submit(function(){
    var checkedCodes = [];
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<originalCodes.length; i++){
      if (userInputCode.value === originalCodes[i]){
        window.location.href = "SomeLinkHere";
        checkedCodes.push(i);
        if (userInputCode.value === checkedCodes[i]){
          $('checked').css('display', 'block');
        }
      }else{
        $('.fake').css('display', 'block');
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fake {display:none;}
.checked{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<p>Product Code: <input type="text" id="userInputCode"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Check" id="submit">
</form>

<h2 class="fake">Your've a Fake product.</h2>
<h2 class="checked">This code was previously authenticated.</h2>
```

I faced trouble in the loop of originalCodes array the if statement can't check all the values.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can avoid loop here to check value in array. use $.inArray

Answer (score 0):

Four mistakes:

- `$('.form')` means elements with class `form`, not the `form` tag. Use `$('form')` instead.
- Once you navigate away with `window.location.href = "SomeLinkHere";`, the JavaScript state is cleared. You'll need to save the checked codes somewhere more persistent if you want to do that.
- You're adding the code to list of checked codes, then seeing if it's there, which it always will be. You need to reverse these.
- If the same code is checked multiple times, `checkedCodes` could eventually get bigger than `originalCodes`, and then your loop will miss some of them.

Comment: Yes, this is not the issue, I just corrected it to $('form') 
This is a mistake due to the write speed.

Comment: @Anas Okay, but that still leaves three more mistakes.